# Getting Node Ranks/Levels in Cytoscape.js Dagre Layout

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to add styling to cytoscape.js nodes based on their level/rank in the graph.

For example, the root node is rank 1, the children of the root node are of rank 2, and so on. Is there a function that returns the node's rank or return a collection of all the nodes with a given rank? Here is an illustration:

```
         Root (rank 1)
        .         .
       .            .
      .               .
   child1 (rank 2)    child2 (rank 2)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you got any idea of this?

Comment: yes, I ended up using node.predecessors() within the cy.js API to traverse the nodes. I also added pre-calculated the rank of each node and included them in the node data as a prop called `rank`. Then, I used the rank number to perform what I needed